# Integrating apollo server v4 with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, apollo

I tried using new `@apollo/server` with NestJS instead of `apollo-server-express`. While using `apollo-server-express`, the `apollo-server-core` package is automatically used and no error is thrown. But when I remove `apollo-server-express` and install `@apollo/server` as dependency. There is the error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-core'
```

Does anyone have any solution ??

Answer (score 2):

There's no official support for Apollo Server v4 with `@nestjs/graphql` yet. You'd have to write a completely custom integration for that, [or wait for this PR](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/2445)

Answer (score 0):

A package for using Apollo Server 4 from NestJS is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@node-libraries/nest-apollo-server).
It works with both Express and Fastify.